# Create an Excel file for each Access file (.mdb) in folder with tables as sheets

Tags: vba, ms-access

#### The task

An external program is continually producing small .mdb database files. The data from the database tables must be loaded into STATA for data processing.

The workflow I've created so far is this:

- Step 1: Use a VBA macro (in Access) to extract the tables into sheets in an Excel workbook
- Step 2: Use another VBA macro (in Excel) to clean the variables for STATA import
- Step 3: Use the plugin xls2dta (in STATA) to merge the sheets into a single .dta file

I can do this for a single file at a time, but I would like to do this in a folder of up to 100 .mbd-files in a single run.

(This question is about step 1 in particular, but I've added the rest as context. If you have a better or more direct route to accomplish the main task, please let me know in a comment).

#### Working code for step 1 for a single file:

The following is the VBA macro I'm using to create the .xls for a single file (a modified version of the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13248627/1685346):

```vb
Sub exportTables2XLS()
    Dim table As DAO.TableDef, database As DAO.Database
    Dim filePath As String, file As String, outFile As String

    filePath = CurrentProject.Path
    file = CurrentProject.Name

    Set database = CurrentDb()

    'Export all tables to outFile
    outFile = filePath & "\" & Left(file, Len(file) - 4) & ".xls"
    For Each table In database.TableDefs
        If Left(table.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
            'Do nothing -- Skip system tables
        Else
            DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
            table.Name, outFile, True, Replace(table.Name, "dbo_", "")
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Almost working code for step 1 as a batch operation

Looping through the folder with `Dir` gives the following:

```vb
Sub batchExportTables2XLS()
    Dim table As DAO.tabledef, database As DAO.database
    Dim file As String, filePath As String, outFile As String
    Dim wrkAcc As Object

    filePath = CurrentProject.Path
    file = Dir(filePath & "/*.mdb")

    Do Until file = ""
        Set wrkAcc = CreateWorkspace("", "admin", "", dbUseJet)
        Set database = wrkAcc.OpenDatabase(file)

        'Export all tables to outFile
        outFile = filePath & "\" & Left(file, Len(file) - 4) & ".xls"
        For Each table In database.TableDefs
            If Left(table.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
                'Do nothing -- Skip system tables
            Else
                DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
                table.Name, outFile, True, Replace(table.Name, "dbo_", "")
            End If
        Next

        file = Dir()
    Loop
End Sub
```

This macro produce a .xls file for each .mdb in the folder, but they all contain sheets corresponding to the tables in the .mdb from where the macro is run. I feel that this is very close, but how can I get the code to produce the correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issues is because `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9,                table.Name, outFile, True, Replace(table.Name, "dbo_", "")` takes places in the current Application instance(aka where the macro is running, in this case the Access Application you've opened).  To change that we need to give it the correct Application to trigger this command.

I've made some adjustments to your code to give you an idea of what to do.  Not sure if you require the Workspace functionality or if that was just what you found on the web, this instead opens a new instance of Access, loads the databases one at a time, and exports the sheets within THAT instance of the Access Application.

```
Sub batchExportTables2XLS()
    Dim table As DAO.TableDef, database As DAO.database
    Dim file As String, filePath As String, outFile As String
    Dim appAccess As New Access.Application


    filePath = CurrentProject.Path
    file = Dir(filePath & "\*.mdb")



    Do Until file = ""
        appAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase filePath & "\" & file


        'Export all tables to outFile
        outFile = filePath & "\" & Left(file, Len(file) - 4) & ".xls"
        For Each table In appAccess.CurrentDb.TableDefs
            If Left(table.Name, 4) = "MSys" Then
                'Do nothing -- Skip system tables
            Else
                appAccess.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, table.Name, outFile, True, Replace(table.Name, "dbo_", "")

            End If
        Next
        appAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase

        file = Dir()
    Loop
    Set appAccess = Nothing
End Sub
```